# problema con traer array desde clases distintas

Tags: java

Tengo un programa en Java que simula los eventos que se producen en un sitio de e-commerce. Mi programa consta de dos clases. Una para categoría de productos y otra para el carro. La primera clase permite al usuario ingresar productos a un array de productos, y con la segunda el usuario decide sin un producto se va al array de carro de compras. Necesito, de esta forma llamar al array de productos de la primera clase (categoría) para traerlo a la segunda (carro de compras) pero no sé como traer arrays entre clases. Existe alguna forma de hacerlo?

CATEGORIA

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Categoria {
    private Scanner teclado;
    private String[] categoria;
    private String[] categoriaMarca;
    public void cargar() {
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        categoria = new String[4];
        categoriaMarca = new String[4];
        System.out.println("Carga de productos");
        for(int f=0; f<categoria.length;f++) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese la categoría del producto ");
            categoria[f] = teclado.next();
            System.out.print("Ingrese la marca del producto ");
            categoriaMarca[f] = teclado.next(); 
        }
    }
    public String getCategoria(int indice) {
        return categoria[indice];
    }
    public String getCategoriaMarca(int indice) {
        return categoriaMarca[indice];
    }
    public void imprimir() {
        for (int f = 0; f<categoria.length;f++) {
            System.out.println(categoria[f] + " - " + categoriaMarca[f]);
        }
    }
}
```

CARRO

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Carro extends Categoria {
    private Scanner teclado;
    private String respuesta1;
    private String respuesta2;
    private int respuesta3;
    private String[] carro;
    public void mostrar() {
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("deseas ver los productos? ");
        respuesta1 = teclado.next();
            if (respuesta1 == "si") {
                System.out.println(getCategoria());
            }
    }
    public void carro() {
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("desea ingresar algún producto al carro? ");
        if (respuesta2 == "si") {
            System.out.println("ingrese el número del producto ");
            respuesta3 = teclado.nextInt();
            if (respuesta3 == 1) {
                carro[1] = categoría[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

APLICACION

```
public class Aplicacion {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        categoria cta = new categoria();
        cta.cargar();
        System.out.println("Lista de productos ingresados: ");
        pv.imprimir();
        Carro cr = new Carro();
        cr.mostrar();
        cr.carro();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente el main debería estar en la clase carro pues es lo más lógico, es la que trabajara con las instancias de la clase Categoria.

De esta forma te creas una instancia de la clase Categoria en el main de la clase Carro y trabajas con ella, justamente coger el código que tienes dentro del main de tu clase Categoria, borrar ese main y crearte un main en la clase Carro con ese código dentro, te he añadido en la clase Categoria unos métodos para poder trabajar con los elementos de los atributos array de la clase Categoria en base a un indice.

CATEGORIA

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Categoria {

    private Scanner teclado;
    private String[] categoria;
    private String[] categoriaMarca;

    public void cargar() {
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        categoria = new String[4];
        categoriaMarca = new String[4];
        System.out.println("Carga de productos");

        for(int f=0; f<categoria.length;f++) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese la categoría del producto ");
            categoria[f] = teclado.next();
            System.out.print("Ingrese la marca del producto ");
            categoriaMarca[f] = teclado.next(); 
        }
    }

    public String getCategoria(int indice){
        return categoria[indice];
    }

    public String getCategoriaMarca(int indice){
        return categoriaMarca[indice];
    }

    public void imprimir() {
        for (int f = 0; f<categoria.length;f++) {
            System.out.println(categoria[f] + " - " + categoriaMarca[f]);
        }
    }
}
```

CARRO

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Carro {

    private Scanner teclado;
    private String respuesta1;
    private String respuesta2;
    private int respuesta3;
    private String[] carro;

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        Categoria pv = new Categoria();
        pv.cargar();
        System.out.println("Lista de productos ingresados: ");
        pv.imprimir();

    }

    public void mostrar() {
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("deseas ver los productos? ");
        respuesta1 = teclado.next();
            if (respuesta1 == "si") {
                //mostrar la lista de productos de la clase categoria;
            }
    }
    public void carro() {
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("desea ingresar algún producto al carro? ");
        if (respuesta2.equals("si")) {
            System.out.println("ingrese el número del producto ");
            respuesta3 = teclado.nextInt();
            if (respuesta3 == 1) {
                //ingresar el primer elemento del array producto al array carro;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Te recomiento trabajar con un objeto de tipo ArrayListy parametrizarlo con el tipo String, como atributo de array de carros en lugar de un array de String normal.

De esta forma puedes usar el método add de la clase ArrayList para añadir una concatenación de getCategoria(indice) + getCategoriaMarca(indice) siendo el indice el numero de producto que quiere añadir al carro la persona - 1.

Esto es porque los indices comienzan por el 0, y supongo que tu quieres que el primero producto sea el 1, asi que si hablamos de un producto 1, este se encontraría en el indice 0, sería:

```
 respuesta3 = teclado.nextInt() - 1;
```

Después de eso en la condición debes tener en cuenta que respuesta3 representa al indice, osea que debes valorar el 0, podrías llamar a respuesta 3 'indice' mejor para aclararte.

Comment: Hice algunos cambios: agregué un objeto más. Ahora hay tres, la clase Categoria, la clase Carro y la clase Aplicación, pero tengo la duda si el array se trae con la clase getCategoria.

Answer (score 0):

He vuelto a la estructura con la clase carro en main, utilizando arraylist, pero al agregar elementos a mi arraylist no puedo solucionar este error: 
"constructor Producto in class Producto cannot be applied to given types; 
required: no arguments 
found: java.lang.String, java.lang.String 
reason: actual and formal argument list differ in length". 
Por lo que he podido ver, este error se produce sobretodo por atributos o variables mal declaradas, pero veo el código y no encuentro nada irregular.

Producto.java

```
public class Producto {
    private String categoria;
    private String categoriaMarca;
    public void Producto(String categoria, String categoriaMarca) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.categoriaMarca = categoriaMarca;
    }
    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }
    public String getCategoriaMarca() {
        return categoriaMarca;
    }
}
```

Aplicacion.java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Aplicacion {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Producto> carro = new ArrayList<Producto>();
        String cat, catMarca;
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            System.out.print("Escriba la categoría: ");
            cat = s.next();
            System.out.print("Escriba la categoría marca: ");
            catMarca = s.next();
            carro.add(new Producto(cat, catMarca));
        }
        Iterator<Producto> iterator = carro.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Producto temp = iterator.next();
            System.out.print(temp.getCategoria());
            System.out.print(temp.getCategoriaMarca());
        }
    }
}
```